# Using Knex, how can the relevant rows of a joined table be given as a nested object?

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

Using knex, how can I get a user's relevant row from the `users` table along with an Array of all the groups for a user with the id=1?

This is my `users` table: [image: https://i.imgur.com/t2psBd4.png]

This is my `groups` table: [image]

And this is my `users_groups` association table: [image]

…I am running this query but it's returning 3 separate rows for the same user:

```js
db("users").join("users_groups", "users.id", "=", "users_groups.user_id").join("groups", "groups.id", "=", "users_groups.group_id").where("users.id", "=", 1)
```

which I believe translates to:

```sql
select * from users inner join users_groups on users.id = users_groups.user_id inner join groups on groups.id = users_groups.group_id where users.id=1
```

The SQL returns: [image]

It's currently returning:

```js
Array(3) [Object, Object, Object]
length:3
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {email:"raj@raj.raj" group_id:1, id:1, name:"step 1", name:"r", role:"superadmin", user_id:1, username:"raj"}
1:Object {email:"raj@raj.raj" group_id:2, id:1, name:"step 2", name:"r", role:"superadmin", user_id:1, username:"raj"}
2:Object {email:"raj@raj.raj" group_id:3, id:1, name:"step 3", name:"r", role:"superadmin", user_id:1, username:"raj"}
```

Stringified, it looks like this

```js
"[{"id":1,"name":"step 1","email":"raj@raj.raj","username":"raj","password":"$2b$10$GbbLTP2sEPS7OKmR4l8RSeX/PUmoIFyNBJb1RIIIrbZa1NNwolHFK","role":"superadmin","created_at":"2020-04-14T12:45:38.138Z","user_id":1,"group_id":1},{"id":2,"name":"step 2","email":"raj@raj.raj","username":"raj","password":"$2b$10$GbbLTP2sEPS7OKmR4l8RSeX/PUmoIFyNBJb1RIIIrbZa1NNwolHFK","role":"superadmin","created_at":"2020-04-14T12:45:38.138Z","user_id":1,"group_id":2},{"id":3,"name":"step 3","email":"raj@raj.raj","username":"raj","password":"$2b$10$GbbLTP2sEPS7OKmR4l8RSeX/PUmoIFyNBJb1RIIIrbZa1NNwolHFK","role":"superadmin","created_at":"2020-04-14T12:45:38.138Z","user_id":1,"group_id":3}]"
```

I'd rather have it return an object representing the single user row, with a nested object for the 3 relevant rows from the `groups` table. For example:

```js
{id:1, name:"raj", groups:[{id:1, name:"step 1"}, {id:2,name:"step 2"}, {id:3,name:"step 3"}]}
```

Is this possible? Or would multiple queries be required and how wasteful is that?

Comment: You should be using an ORM like objection.js and `.withGraphFetched()` method to get related objects as nested objects. Using objection.js is just kind of utility layer on top of knex, which doesn't cause any additional overhead, but gives you bunch of additional features, which makes developing an app easier.

Answer (score 2):

Knex is not able to aggregate flat data as you needed. You should do it yourself.

```js
(await db('users')
  .join('users_groups', 'users.id', '=', 'users_groups.user_id')
  .join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'users_groups.group_id')
  .where('users.id', '=', 1)
  )
  .reduce((result, row) => {
    result[row.id] = result[row.id] || {
      id: row.id,
      username: row.username,
      email: row.email,
      groups: [],
    };

    result[row.id].groups.push({ id: row.group_id, name: row.name });
    return result;
  }, {});
```

Comment: This returns the original Array with the 3 objects, but with the group for that row as a single object in an array of its own. As such: https://paste.ee/p/YO5EZ

Comment: Here's a stringified version of the result: https://paste.ee/p/W3hM7

Comment: I’m not sure what is the question here, did my code made some sense?

Comment: I get your general point, but this code returns paste.ee/p/YO5EZ instead of https://paste.ee/p/77OUq . The target structure is a single object with a `groups` key containing an array of the relevant `groups` table columns for user with id=1.

Comment: OK? so structure it as you need it to be, base your code on my example.

Comment: Thanks for a general approach.